# Is there a way to use numpy.outer on only a subset of dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-ufunc

I have an array of arrays, like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
```

I would like to calculate the pairwise differences between the array elements, something like:

```
[[[ 0,  0,  0], [-3, -3, -3]],
 [[ 3,  3,  3], [ 0,  0,  0]]
```

My first thought was to use `np.subtract.outer(a, a)`, but that doesn't do what I want - it goes one layer too deep into the arrays. I can see that the numbers I need are in the output of `np.subtract.outer(a, a)`, but the array that I'm actually working with is very large, and I don't have enough memory to be able to allocate for the result.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use broadcasting to solve this.

```
a[:, None, :] - a[None, :, :]
```

Gives you what you want.

Comment: Thank you! I knew that there was an easy solution that I wasn't seeing.